# Finding the MGF of sum of squares of independent normal random variables, with non-zero mean?

Tags: distributions, moment-generating-function

I have a question where I'm given $n$ independent random variables $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$, following a normal distribution with non-zero mean $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ and constant common variance.
It then asks to compute the MGF of the sum of squares of each of these $X_i$. How would I do this? I know that squaring $N(0,1)$ gives chi-squared with df=1, so I can assume the MGF of this, but this doesn't seem to help right now.

Answer (score 3):

(This looks like self-study so I provide the following hint)

Let $E(X_i) = a_i$ and $Y_i = X_i^2 = (a_i + Z_i)^2$ where $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$. THen
$$Y_i = a_i^2 + Z_i^2 + 2a_iZ_i\,.$$

Then,

$$\sum Y_i = \sum a_i^2 + \sum Z_i^2 + \sum a_iZ_i $$

You know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i^2 \sim \chi^2_n$ and that $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$. You can then use the basic properties of MGF to obtain the MGF of $\sum Y_i$.